# Extending Windbg limit above 1MB?

Tags: windbg

I am currently trying to run scripts in Windbg (x64). However, the script I am trying to read exceeds 1MB and because of that, I am getting the error "Command file execution failed, Win32 error 0n87. The parameter is incorrect". Does anyone know how I could increase the limit in Windbg so that I could pass in scripts that are 10MB? Thanks!

Error as is shown in windbg:

```
$t2=00000000037b9db8
Address            Gen   Heap   segment            begin              allocated           size
00000000037b9db8   2      0     0000000003430000   0000000003431000   00000000043e8fb0    0x78(120)
Command file execution failed, Win32 error 0n87
    "The parameter is incorrect."
```

Comment: What sort of script is that?

Comment: I just run the scripts so I might not have the right info. Basically, we have a script that will be used with "$$>a< ...". Once that command is ran, the script will look into another text file and go line by line until it finds a condition that matches what it is looking for. Once it find the line, the command located in that logical block is executed.  The problem is, the text files we look in are usually above 1 MB of size and contain if/else functions along with other windbg commands. Additionally, we continue the process of looking in the text file until all conditions are tested.

Comment: I have no idea why windbg gives the "command file execution failed, Win32 error 0n87" error whenever the text files I look into exceeds 1 MB in size. I am hoping there is a setting in Windbg I can tweak that would allow me to increase that size to a much larger number but I haven't seen anything that would do the trick.

Comment: From that description, it sounds more like this is not a limitation of the script size that is run with `$$>a<`. I have the impression that the script imposes a restriction on the text file that is procesed. Maybe the script allocates 1 MB of memory with `.dvalloc` and then reads the text file into that memory. It's hard to tell without more details.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will see if that leads to something. In the meantime, I pasted the full error up above. It seems to be centered around $t2 and the not really sure with the size:120 means.

Comment: I know that the 120 is the decimal version of 0x78. I don't know what the 120 means in this context nor where 120 was defined.

Comment: `Gen` looks like a generation of a garbage collected heap. Since there is no Java support, it will be .NET. The output is probably from the command `!gcwhere` which is used with `$t2` as parameter. Still, without a [mcve], this question is hard to answer

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help and sorry about not providing a lot of information. Apparently, the error seemed to occur when the file size exceeded 1MB and fixed-name aliases were used in the text file. As a workaround, normal aliases were used and the limitation was exceeded.